# How to dispatch ThunkAction with redux-thunk and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I am having trouble with dispatching a redux-thunk action using Typescript.

```
import { AnyAction, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunk, { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

interface State {
  counter: number
}

const initialState: State = {
  counter: 10
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action: AnyAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return { counter: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function increment(): ThunkAction<void, State, unknown, AnyAction> {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'increment',
      payload: 20
    })
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

store.dispatch(increment())
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
Argument of type 'ThunkAction<void, State, unknown, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<void, State, unknown, AnyAction>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

I have tried multiple different thinkgs for action type such as custom interface, Action etc. and nothing works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default `dispatch` type does not know of thunk, as the "base redux" types are not very powerful. So you'll have to cast it to ThunkDispatch manually:

```
(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<State, unknown, AnyAction>)(increment())
```

Just as a PSA: The type of redux you are writing here (vanilla redux with hand-written actions, action-types, switch-case statements and immutable logic in reducers) is no longer the "officially recommended approach" of writing redux.
Please take a look at [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and best follow the official, up-to-date [redux tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index), as you are most likely following a very outdated one.

Redux Toolkit is also a *lot* easier to use in general, and specially with TypeScript (and `store.dispatch` will have the correct type if you use it ;) )

Comment: This works. I just want to point out that I am using redux without React and as far I know redux-toolkit assumes you are using React.

Comment: @jm18457 it does not. It is completely framework-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Just a kick advise for those who are struggling with the dispatch function when using thunk and hooks.

Here is an example of what am I doing to manage authentication state, fetching data from graphql server. The magic is coming when defining the dispatch Type `type IAppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<IAppState, any, IAppActions>;`

**store.ts**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkDispatch, ThunkMiddleware } from "redux-thunk";
import { authReducer } from "./reducers/authReducers";
import { IAuthActions } from "./types/authTypes";

const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
        : compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authReducer,
});

type IAppActions = IAuthActions; <-- merge here other actions
type IAppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
type IAppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<IAppState, any, IAppActions>; <--here is the magic

const reduxStore = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware<IAppDispatch, any>(
            thunkMiddleware as ThunkMiddleware<IAppState, IAppActions, any>
        )
    )
);

export { reduxStore, IAppState, IAppDispatch, IAppActions };
```

**authActions** (actions creator and dispatch thunk actions)

```
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import {
    loginMutation,
    logoutMutation,
} from "../../components/DataComponents/Authentification/fetchAuthentification";
import { GqlSessionUser } from "../../components/DataComponents/generatedTypes";
import {
    IAuthActions,
    IAuthErrorAction,
    IAuthLoadingAction,
    IAuthLoginAction,
    IAuthLogoutAction,
} from "../types/authTypes";

const authLogin = (appUserId: GqlSessionUser): IAuthLoginAction => {
    return {
        type: "AUTH_LOGIN",
        payload: {
            appUserId,
        },
    };
};

const authLogout = (): IAuthLogoutAction => {
    return {
        type: "AUTH_LOGOUT",
    };
};

const authLoadingAction = (isLoading: boolean): IAuthLoadingAction => {
    return {
        type: "AUTH_LOADING",
        payload: {
            isLoading,
        },
    };
};

const authErrorAction = (errorMessage: string): IAuthErrorAction => {
    return {
        type: "AUTH_ERROR",
        payload: {
            errorMessage,
        },
    };
};


const authLoginAction = (idOrEmail: string) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<IAuthActions>) => {
        dispatch(authLoadingAction(true));
        const { data, errors } = await loginMutation(idOrEmail); <--fetch data from GraphQl

        if (data) {
            dispatch(authLogin(data.login.data[0]));
        }
        if (errors) {
            dispatch(authErrorAction(errors[0].message));
        }

        dispatch(authLoadingAction(false));

        return true;
    };
};

const authLogoutAction = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<IAuthActions>) => {
        dispatch(authLoadingAction(true));
        await logoutMutation(); <--fetch data from GraphQl
        dispatch(authLogout());
        dispatch(authLoadingAction(false));

        return true;
    };
};

export {
    authLoginAction,
    authLogoutAction,
    authLoadingAction,
    authErrorAction,
};
```

**example of components that use state and dispatch async actions via useDispatch**

***please not how dispatch is typed as IAppDispatch, although it is imported from react-redux***

```
    import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
    authLoginAction,
    authLogoutAction,
} from "../../../stateManagement/actions/authActions";
import { IAppDispatch, IAppState } from "../../../stateManagement/reduxStore";
import Button from "../../Button";

const Authentification: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
        const dispatch: IAppDispatch = useDispatch(); <--typing here avoid "type missing" error

        const isAuth = useSelector<IAppState>((state) => state.authReducer.isAuth);
    
        const authenticate = async (idOrEmail: string): Promise<void> => {
            if (!isAuth) {
                dispatch(authLoginAction(idOrEmail)); <--dispatch async action through thunk
            } else {
                dispatch(authLogoutAction()); <--dispatch async action through thunk
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <Button
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: "inherit",
                    color: "#FFFF",
                }}
                onClick={() => authenticate("jerome_altariba@carrefour.com")}
            >
                {isAuth && <p>Logout</p>}
                {!isAuth && <p>Login</p>}
            </Button>
        );
    };
    export { Authentification };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the issue recently when tried to upgrade my app from HOC connect to use hooks. As I'm not using `redux-toolkit` (for historical reasons), it was a bit confusing how to use it all correctly with the typescript. The solution is based on some old `create-react-app` with typescript template. I have finished up with this what seems to be working:

**store.ts**

```js
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

export interface ApplicationState { 
    sliceName: SliceType
    // other store slices
}

export interface AppThunkAction<TAction> {
    (dispatch: (action: TAction) => void, getState: () => ApplicationState): void;
}

export const useStoreSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<ApplicationState> = useSelector;
export const useStoreDispatch = () => useDispatch<ThunkDispatch<ApplicationState, unknown, AnyAction>>();
```

**storeSlice.ts**

```js
import { AppThunkAction } from './index';

export interface StandardReduxAction { type: 'STANDARD_REDUX' }
export interface ReduxThunkAction { type: 'REDUX_THUNK', data: unknown }

interface SliceNameActions {
    standardRedux: (show: boolean) => StandardReduxAction;
    reduxThunk: () => AppThunkAction<ReduxThunkAction>;
}

export const SliceNameActionCreators: SliceNameActions = {

    standardRedux: (): StandardReduxAction => { type: StandardReduxAction };

    reduxThunk: (): AppThunkAction<ReduxThunkAction> => async (dispatch, getState): Promise<void> => {
                    
        let response = await asyncCallSomewhere();
        dispatch({ type: ReduxThunkAction, data: response });
    }
}
```

**anyComponent.tsx**

```js
import { useStoreDispatch } from 'store';
import { SliceNameActionCreators } from 'storeSlice';

const dispatch = useStoreDispatch();

const dispatchStandardRedux = () => dispatch(SliceNameActionCreators.standardRedux());
const dispatchReduxThunk = () => dispatch(SliceNameActionCreators.reduxThunk());
```

The currently recommended way of setting up `React-Redux` with typescript is using `Redux Toolkit`, a guide can be found [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types).